# What is the equivalent of this objective-c code in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What is the alternative code in swift of this code ?

```
static inline CGFloat randomInRangeScale(CGFloat scale)
{
    CGFloat value = arc4random_uniform(INT16_MAX);
    return value * 0.000015 + 0.8 ;
}
```

I tried this:

```
func randomInRangeScale(scale : CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    let value : CGFloat = arc4random_uniform(UInt16);
    return value * 0.000015 + 0.8 ;
}
```

But it gives me an error `"Cannot invoke 'arc4random_uniform' with an argument list of type '((UInt16).Type)"`

Comment: You should post what have you tried.

Comment: inline in swift will can be get like @inline and can use UInt16.max

Comment: Obviously Int16.max if you want the equivalent of INT16_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter type of the `arc4random_uniform` is `UInt32`, so you have to cast the `UINT16_MAX` to `UInt32` and cast the value to `CGFloat`.

Try this:

```
func randomInRangeScale(scale : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let value = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UINT16_MAX));
    return CGFloat(value) * 0.000015 + 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
func randomInRangeScale(scale : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max))
    let randomCGFloat = CGFloat(random)
    return randomCGFloat * 0.000015 + 0.8
}
```

Comment: @Avt This answer fixed a compile error that your answer has. The return value of  `arc4random_uniform` is `UInt32`, not `CGFloat`.

Comment: @Avt: You were passing a `UInt16` as param to `arc4random_uniform`. Your code did not work. Then you edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as an extension on CGFloat like -

```
extension CGFloat {
static func randomFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max))) * 0.000015 + 0.8
     }
}
```

and call it using -

```
CGFloat.randomFloat()
```

After running some tests that involved calling it in a loop 100 million times on the main thread and it seems faster than if the same function is implemented as a method.

Here's the test -

```
let loopIterationCount = 100000000
    var timestamp = NSDate()
    for var k = 0 ; k < loopIterationCount ; k++ {
        let x = CGFloat.randomFloat()
    }
    var timeStampEnd = NSDate()
    println("CGFloat extension took \(self.timeDifference(timestamp, endTime: timeStampEnd)) seconds.")

    timestamp = NSDate()
    for var k = 0 ; k < loopIterationCount ; k++ {
        let x = self.randomFloat()
    }
    timeStampEnd = NSDate()
    println("function took \(self.timeDifference(timestamp, endTime: timeStampEnd)) seconds.")

func randomFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max))) * 0.000015 + 0.8
}

func timeDifference(startTime: NSDate, endTime: NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
}
```

The result

> CGFloat extension took 3.19389200210571 seconds.
>
> function took 5.25490999221802 seconds.